Nextcloud allow iFrames
I'm getting a little bit desperate with my nextcloud instance...
I want to embed it as an iframe on my own website on the same server.
Butt all browsers that I'm using complain the same:

Refused to frame 'https://nextcloud.mydomain.de/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

Does anyone experience the same? Any ideas?
I've read and tried out this post:

https://return2.net/nextcloud-enable-external-iframe/

I've changed the php config to the following:

I've made a recursive grep over the whole nextcloud lib directory searching for where 'allowedDomains' or 'allowedAncestors' or 'frame-ancestors' are set.
I've set the following headers in apache:

